# KEIL: The reason for working a MUL within a loop only in the 1st iteration

Tags: loops, assembly, arm, multiplication, keil

I have written a code in keil in which there is a loop containing a multiplication which can be done either by shift left by 1 or MUL command. However, both are executed only in the 1st iteration and in the next ones, compiler executes the code, while nothing happens.
Is there someone who knows the probable reason?
Thanks

```
Here is the code of the loop:
loop            ADD r9, r9, #1              
                ;MUL r8, r7, r11 ;double the X
                LSL r12, r7, #1
                CMP r12, r4 ;CMP the X with P
                BHI G1
                BLS G0
```

Comment: yeap, I know. Conventional way to execute code again is to jump back at the beginning of the `loop`. I have feeling that neither `G1` or `G0` doing that

Comment: Both are doing your point but it is not executed. I can send you G1 and G0. In the following iterations, ADD r9, r9, #1 is executed but not the following line (LSL)

Comment: Do not send me, edit question to have proper code example

Comment: Is this self-modifying code, that changes the machine-code bytes of the `lsl` instruction so it's now a NOP?  What do you mean it "doesn't execute"?  Do you mean it runs like a NOP, so single-stepping in a debugger still stops on it and before the next instruction, or do you mean it's not there at all?  And no change in any register values?  Was `r12` already equal to `r7 + r7`?  In that case it would be normal that there was no change in machine state other than incrementing program-counter.

Answer (score -1):

it was solved. it occured because this is a consecutive shift and it should be shifted by 1 at each iteration. the written code copies the source into destination and then, shift by 1. So it is not modified after the 1st iteration. the solution is modifying r7 by LSL r7, #1. This is shifted r7 by 1 position at all iterations.

Comment: This answer is not really good understandable. Please explain. And format the code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).